# checking a password in a loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am writing a simple program where a user enters a password to use a directory system.

If the user choses not to enter any details I want to log them out and then give them the option to log back in again. I have tried doing this with a loop (see code below) but when I reset the passQ vairable to 0 I was expecting it to log the user out and return to the opening statement in the loop... but that doesnt happen.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

I tried adding break; (commented out bellow) but this just ended the program.

p.s. I know this way of managing the password isn't really secure, I was just having a play as I may want to use loops like this for other things in the future.

```
package directory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Directory {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
//-------------//
//Main Meathod //
//-------------//
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //------------------//
    // Define Variables //
    //------------------//
    String question = "Y";
    String passQ    = "0";
    String password = "password";

    Scanner passCheck = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Chris Headleands Tel Directory, Enter Password to access sytems"); //1 and 0 used for yes and no
    question = passCheck.nextLine(); // Next line used to decide if the user wants to enter a persons details
    while (passQ != password)
    {
        if (question.equalsIgnoreCase("password")) //Do they want to ender a person? 1 == yes
        {

            //Create a new array list for the people created
            ArrayList<TelEntry> directory = new ArrayList<TelEntry>();

            //Check if the user wants to create a new person
            Scanner checker = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("would you like to add a directory entry(1 = Yes / 0 = NO!)"); //1 and 0 used for yes and no
            question = checker.nextLine(); // Next line used to decide if the user wants to enter a persons details

            if (question.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) //Do they want to ender a person? 1 == yes
            {
                while (question.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) // Add a loop so multiple people can be added
                {

                    String name; // First name
                    String telNo; // Last name

                    // Create scanner for entering details
                    Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in);

                    //----------------------------------//
                    //User to enter details via keyboard//
                    //----------------------------------//

                    // Ask user to set first name
                    System.out.println("Enter their first name");
                    name = keybd.nextLine();

                    // Ask user to set last name
                    System.out.println("Enter their last name");
                    telNo = keybd.nextLine();

                    // -------------------------------------//
                    //Add the new person to personlist array//
                    //--------------------------------------//
                    directory.add(new TelEntry(name, telNo));

                    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    // Check to see if the user wants to add another person, if Y then re-run loop //
                    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    Scanner newChecker = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.print("would you like to enter another person? (1 = Yes / 0 = NO!)");
                    question = newChecker.nextLine();  

                }


            }

            //--------------------------------------------------------------//
            // User doesnt want to add any people to the persontest program //
            //--------------------------------------------------------------//
            if (question.equalsIgnoreCase("testmode"))
            {
                System.out.println("you are now in test mode")
            }
            else
            { // Provide the user with a witty retort                     
                System.out.println("if your not going to use me for what I was designed to do, bugger off and bother someone else!");
                System.out.println("Logging out");
                passQ = "0"; // Reset password loop
                // break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

This will *always* be `true`:

```
while (passQ != password)
```

as `passQ` and `password` do not refer to the same `String` instance. Use `.equals()` to compare the content of two `String` instances. However, I see nowhere in the code where `passQ` or `password` are set to different values so even if:

```
while (!passQ.equals(password))
```

were used this would still be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your while condition

```
   while (!passQ.equals(password))
```

Or replace it with below please post code above while loop.

```
  if (passCheck.hasNextInt()) { //check whether user has entered numeric value
        if (passCheck.nextInt() == 0) { //if 0 close the program 
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `while (!passQ.equals(password))` 
always use `equals()` method to compare strings.